# POST request problems during JSON response using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am having an issue while using `JSON` server for login form. I have login credentials like `Username and password` and trying to execute it. I have used `POST` on the server, specifying username and password inserted by the user. The server should execute a query on the **specified condition**, to check if there are any rows with that name and password. If yes return true, if false return false. then the client should parse this response.

This is my HTML code :

```
<form ng-submit="loginform(logcred)" name="logform"><br/><br>
<tr ng-repeat="logcred in loginfo"></tr>
<div>
    <label form="emailinput"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="uname" id="emailinput" placeholder="you@example.com" ng-model="logcred.username" >
</div>
<div>
    <label form="pwdinput"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwdinput" placeholder="*******" ng-model="logcred.password">
</div>
<div>
    <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
</div>  
</form>
```

This is the Javascript code using AngularJS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('credientials', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/loginfo')
 .then(
 function successCallback(response){
 $scope.loginfo == response.data;

$scope.loginform = function(loginfo,username,password){
console.log(loginfo);
$http({
    url :'http://localhost:3000/loginfo',
    method : 'POST',
    data : loginfo
    })
.then(
  function successCallback(response){
  $scope.loginfo = response.data;
if (username === username && password === password) {
    console.log(response);
}
    else
    {
        console.log("Error: " + response)
    }
    });
}
});
```

I am getting the response properly from my server. But when I match the data using `POST` request using `if` condition, there I am not understanding what mistake I am doing ?

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you get in `response.data` ?

Comment: In `get` method, i'm getting username and password from my server. In `post` i'm getting the entered username and password from the user

Answer (score 0):

i didnt understand if your problem is server side or client ? is your problem at

```
if (username === username && password === password) {
console.log(response);
```

}

you may use == insted of ====

Comment: Its on client side

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the data with itself.

```
username === username && password === password
```

Should be

```
username === $scope.loginfo.username && password === $scope.loginfo.password
```

Still, any kind of security validation should be done on the server rather than on the client.

Also, you seem to be new to Angular. Let me recommend to you the [John Papa's Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).

Comment: yea . I am to new angular. I tried the code what you have posted , but i got undefined `loginfo`